# ng-switch with shared options

Tags: angularjs, refactoring, ng-switch

I have an ng-switch statement I want to refactor. It looks like this:

```
<div ng-switch on="property.type">
    <input type="text" ng-switch-when="string" ng-model="property.value" placeholder="Property value">
    <select ng-switch-when="bool" ng-model="property.value" ng-options="value for value in [true,false]" placeholder="Property value"></select>
    <input type="number" ng-switch-when="int" ng-model="property.value" placeholder="Property value">
    <input type="text" ng-switch-default ng-model="property.value" placeholder="Property value">
</div>
```

You can notice that the `ng-model` and `placeholder` options are identical to all cases. My question is: can I refactor this somehow to have these options only written once?

Thanks! Uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not completely refactored to avoid all duplication, you can reduce a bit of it by combining the input tags:

```
<div ng-switch on="property.type">
  <select ng-switch-when="bool" ng-model="property.value" ng-options="value for value in [true,false]" placeholder="Property value"></select>
  <input type="{{property.type == 'int' ? 'number' : 'string'}}" ng-switch-default ng-model="property.value" placeholder="Property value">
</div>
```

This can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/FybDC1I4U7rSC6GZJ3az

If this was a project I was working on, I suspect I would not refactor it further, leave the small amount of repeated markup, in order to keep what's going on clear.